# Node js Как закрыть запрос без изменения страницы

Tags: node.js, express, request

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public') + '/test/' + req.body.list,
      req.body.file,function(err){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
  res.end()
});
```

Как я могу закрыть запрос так, чтобы осталась текущая страница и ничего не перезагрузилось.
Если я пишу res.end() откроется новая пустая страница

Comment: что Вы подразумеваете под `закрыть запрос`? и как Вы грузите файлы?

Comment: возможно 302 или рядом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Только при использовании AJAX запросов